# Postgres Как привести текст в int не зная число знаков?

Tags: postgresql

есть замечательная функция `to_number(text, text)`

но я должен указать число знаков. например `to_number('2323-f', '99999')`

а если я не знаю число знаков?

Answer (score 1):

to_number требует не число знаков, а формат, в котором представлено число в текстовом значении.
Можно также воспользоваться функцией cast
`cast('12345' as numeric)`
Или  упрощённым видом записи
`'12345'::numeric`
Думаю, этого варианта вам за глаза. Ну а если нет, что же, придётся разбираться в форматах представления чисел.

Comment: нет мне нужно не сменить тип а преобразовать. то есть формат записи 123-ы где нужно отбросить не цифры

Comment: А что есть изменение типа? Преобразование одного типа в другой :)
Не цифры можно и replace-ом из текста вырезать.